# JSON Exception - No value for wanted parameter

Tags: java, android, json, listview, jsoup

I am developing an app on the android platform that gets youtube video search results as a JSON format and puts the title, channel name, and thumbnail url into a listview. I should also add that I am using the jsoup library for android. Pretty much I am connecting to a URL that contains a JSON response and am trying to use values from that response and apply them to a listview. 
Here is the method.

```
public void initSearch(String searchQuery) {
    String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=1&order=rating&q=" + searchQuery + "&key=MY_GOOGLE_API_KEY";

    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).ignoreContentType(true).timeout(10 * 1000).get();
        String getJson = doc.text();

        try{
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(getJson).nextValue();

            String videoId = jsonObject.getString("videoId");
            String thumbnail = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + videoId + "/mqdefault.jpg";
            String title = (String)jsonObject.get("title");
            String channelTitle = (String)jsonObject.get("channelTitle");

            VideoDetails videoDetails = new VideoDetails(thumbnail, title,channelTitle,"6,900" );
            searchedList.add(videoDetails);
        } catch (JSONException e){ 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmdXv.png) is what the webpage I am connecting to looks like.

I have already checked if it is valid JSON format, and yes it is.

Now the problem is, nothing is actually added to my list view. When this method is called I receive an error that looks like this.

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for videoId
```

Anyone know whats going on? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is searchQuery value? i want to test it.

Comment: the searchQuery value ccomes from a SearchView I have implemented into the MainActivity. I just used 'dogs' as the searchQuery term.

Comment: keep in mind you will have to change the api key at the end of the url to get an authorized request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `videoId` is a sub-element in the JSON, so you need to traverse the JSON to get it.

Bad way (note the hard coded index):

```
String videoID = (String) ((JSONObject) ((JSONObject) jsonObject.getJSONArray("items").get(0)).get("id")).get("videoId");
System.out.println(videoID);
```

Preferred way:

```
Iterator<?> keys = jsonObject.keys();

/* Iterate over all the elements and sub-elements and assign as 
 * needed. Based on the type you can concert each item to a JSONObject or 
 * JSONArray, etc.
 */
while (keys.hasNext()) {
    String key = (String) keys.next();

    System.out.println(key + "\t" + jsonObject.get(key) + "\t" + jsonObject.get(key).getClass());
}
```

Comment: thank you, I am very new to JSON so I don't really know how to navigate in it. when i ran your preferred way in the debugger I noticed that some of the classes that are returned are different from the rest. more specifically, the "items" key is marked as a JSONArray. how do i navigate through that? nested while loops? if it is possible could you send me some source code? again, thank you so much I am coming much closer to getting my desired values.

Comment: @Mason JSONArray behaves like a list, so when you find one you can assign it to a JSONArray variable and it will have methods like `size` and `get` which you can use in a loop to get all the values. `JSONArray a = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get(key);`