# Java get first YouTube result from a search term

Tags: java, json, youtube-api, jsoup

I'm currently trying to program a Bot in Discord using Java and am now trying to make it play music using a provided search term.

For that, I'd need to get the video ID of the first result and turn it to its valid URL form. I've already tried to do it via the **YouTube Data API v3** and got pretty close but for some reason it throws an Exeception.

This is my code so far. (taken from [here](http://www.joe0.com/2016/03/05/youtube-data-api-v3-how-to-search-youtube-using-java-and-extract-video-id-of-the-most-relevant-result/))

```java
if(!isValidURL(identifier)) {   //checks if the provided argument should be interpreted as a search term
            try { 
                String keyword = identifier;
                keyword = keyword.replace(" ", "+");

                String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=1&order=rating&q=" + keyword + "&key=MY_KEY";

                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(1000).get();  //May throw IOException, hence the try/catch

                String getJson = doc.text();
                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(getJson ).nextValue();

                identifier = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + jsonObject.getString("videoId");  //finished URL
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

And this is the error message. (`UnsupportedMimeTypeException`)

```
org.jsoup.UnsupportedMimeTypeException: Unhandled content type. Must be text/*, application/xml, or application/xhtml+xml. Mimetype=application/json; charset=UTF-8, URL=https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet...
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:770)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:705)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:295)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:284)
```

Comment: Not sure, but is this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16329756/1710831) answer relevant?

Comment: @SchautDollar It was! I managed to narrow the error down to a JSONException and was able to fix it using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45528247/json-exception-no-value-for-wanted-parameter/45528426). Thanks for the help!